# THREEjs normal shader that will work with controlnet

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, shader, vertex-shader

how can i write this normal shader so it works to bypass  the preprocessor for controlnet
https://jsfiddle.net/lunchie/mpuanxL3/4/

```js
    skinnedMesh.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        vertexShader: [
              '#include <skinning_pars_vertex>',
              'varying vec3 vNormal;',
    
              'void main() {',
    
                '#include <skinbase_vertex>',
                '#include <begin_vertex>',
                '#include <skinning_vertex>',
                '#include <project_vertex>',
    
                'mat4 skinMatrix = boneMatX * skinWeight.x + boneMatY * skinWeight.y + boneMatZ * skinWeight.z + boneMatW * skinWeight.w;',
                'vNormal = (skinMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;',
              '}'
               ].join( '\n' ),
               fragmentShader: [
                 'varying vec3 vNormal;',
                 'void main() {',
                 '       gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(vNormal), 1.0);',
                 '}'
               ].join( '\n' ),
             skinning: true
        } );
```

it dose not seem to be the same format that controlnet uses for normals, it gives images like this [image]

Comment: Do you really want the color channels to go negative? You won’t be able to see anything from `[-1, 0]` because anything below 0 is black. Typically normal materials do a shift of range from `[-1, 1] to [0, 1]` so you can see it better. Do you have an image of the desired output?

Comment: abs() stops them from being negitive no? but that put me on the track i probobly want somthing like (x,y,z+1) /2 not abs i thought it looked a little bright

Answer (score 2):

The way Three.js and most 3D renderers show their normals is by shifting the range from `[-1, 1]` to a visible color range of `[0, 1]`. It's a simple equation:

```glsl
gl_FragColor = vec4(vNormal * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0);
```

or sometimes your skinnnedMesh might stretch the normals, so you want to scale them back down to have a length of 1 with:

```glsl
gl_FragColor = vec4(normalize( vNormal ) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0);
```

This should be your result, [just like `MeshNormalMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshNormalMaterial):

[image]